# Making an array of keys from json in postgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have column "elements" in table which is having a json(array json) row values which looks like this

| elements |
| --- |
| [{"key":12,"value":"qw"},{"key":13,"value":"fa"}] |
| [{"key":32,"value":"24"},{"key":321,"value":"21"}] |

I want to make an column of arrays for every row which consist of keys extracted from that row's json values ,my desired column "result" may look like this

| elements | result |
| --- | --- |
| [{"key":12,"value":"qw"},{"key":13,"value":"fa"}] | {12,13} |
| [{"key":32,"value":"24"},{"key":321,"value":"21"}] | {32,321} |

is there a way to do it? thank you

Comment: Is the data type of this column really json or does only the data looks like a json, but the data type of this column is varchar or anything else?

Comment: It was varchar but i converted them to json array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select elements::text,
       array_agg(value->>'key') 
from your_table, json_array_elements(elements)
group by 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Schema (PostgreSQL v13)**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  elements json
);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('[{"key":12,"value":"qw"},{"key":13,"value":"fa"}]');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('[{"key":32,"value":"24"},{"key":321,"value":"21"}]');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select elements::text, array_agg(cast(value->>'key' as integer)) as result 
from test, json_array_elements(elements)
group by 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

| elements | result |
| --- | --- |
| [{"key":12,"value":"qw"},{"key":13,"value":"fa"}] | 12,13 |
| [{"key":32,"value":"24"},{"key":321,"value":"21"}] | 32,321 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6WrNWhP7bQefb6uZHQigHD/1)

Comment: Well done, thank you. But I think you also should add ORDER BY 1 after the GROUP BY 1